# Event sourcing: detect field changes automatically with Entity Framework

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework, event-sourcing

I'm implementing event sourcing from scratch using ASP.NET Core 7 and PosgreSQL and I have use case when I have to track 20 columns of aggregate, some fields values are changed or removed.

Also, Entity Framework change tracker is used to detect which columns were modified. But now I'm not sure what is the best payload structure.

There are couple of solutions:

1. To have a dictionary that contains updated column name and new value. But it sounds not good because it is not type safe and in the future it can be complicated to maintain.

   ```
   fields = new Dictionary<string, (object OldValue, object NewValue)>
                {
                    { "Name", (customer.Name, "Jonathan Smith") },
                    { "Email", (customer.Email, "jsmith@example.com") },
                    { "Phone", (customer.Phone, "555-5678") }
                }
   ```
2. Create two different events for updated and removed columns

Perhaps there is a better way to handle each field updates in events with introducing less complexion?

- To have each event for each property is not good because it's going to introduce lots of simple events and code duplication.

Comment: A series of concepts around event sourcing needs to be clarified. First, the Aggregate table in Event Store does not have such a quantity of columns in event sourcing. I presume you are looking for a projection strategy. For this, you need to model events as business facts and use these facts individually to update the projections. Here is a project that applies those principles: https://github.com/AntonioFalcaoJr/EventualShop

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to read more about what is Event in EventSourcing, because now it looks like you're going into anti-pattern named property sourcing https://event-driven.io/pl/property-sourcing/.
To unleash the full power (decision-making, keep context of changes) you should model your Domain Events as some business fact like: `OrderAccepted` than `OrderChanged(newValues / oldValues)` - which is very technical. Do not couple events to some state representation (like 20 columns in aggregate - which is probably too big - looks like Aggregate it's User which is the most common case of mixed Bounded Contextes into one Aggregate).

I think those resources may be helpful in your case:

- https://verraes.net/2019/05/ddd-msg-arch/ - many short articles, very informative
- https://martendb.io/ - existing implementation for .NET Event Store based on Postgres

Good luck in discovering the exciting world of the Event Sourcing! :)